# How to combine highcharts data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I found the example for using grouped categories highchart here :

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: "container",
        type: "column",
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: '#e8eaeb',
        borderRadius: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'
    },
    title: {
        style: {
            'fontSize': '1em'
        },
        useHTML: true,
        x: -27,
        y: 8,
        text: '<span class="chart-title"> Grouped categories <span class="chart-href"> <a href="http://www.blacklabel.pl/highcharts" target="_blank"> Black Label </a> </span> <span class="chart-subtitle">plugin by </span></span>'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
    }],
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{
            name: "Fruit",
            categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
        }, {
            name: "Vegetable",
            categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
        }, {
            name: "Fish",
            categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
        }]
    }
});
```

});

and the example for make multiple column by categories here :

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    }]
});
```

});

now my question is : **How to combine two chart? I want each categories have multiple column like demo 2**

Comment: [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/TFhd7/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=TFhd7)              [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) Link to JsFiddel

Comment: Add multiple serie in the series object, like in the second demo. http://jsfiddle.net/4pmnaw28/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add multiple serie in the series object, like in the second demo.

```
series: [{
        data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
    },{
        data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
    },{
        data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
    },{
        data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
    }],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4pmnaw28/1.